# Trying to get xjsinteropmode JS working

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I'm trying to try out vaadin polymer elements with GWT and I'm having a heck of time getting going. I'm using GWT 2.8 SNAPSHOT in Eclipse and I cannot get a basic project to run because of XjsInteropmode. The error says to add it to Super Dev Mode, so I've added it to the run arguments as well as the GWT compile arguments and I'm still getting an error saying to double check that I'm compiling with the -XjsInteropmode JS' flag... What am I missing?

Comment: How do I even set this flag to the code server?

Comment: I tried in 2 different places 
right click on the project > GWT Compile > open up arguments
or
right click project > run as > run configurations > select your configuration and then look for the tab that says arguments.

Answer (score 0):

2.8 snapshot already used the [new specs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit#heading=h.lsr32vixbrnm):
use `-generateJsInteropExports` instead of `-XjsInteropmode`

Comment: I tried that and then got this error.

https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9223 . 

It looks like they have solved it but not patched it in? If they haven't then I'm not sure what to do as I don't know how to recompile the snapshot.

Comment: uhm well...looks like that. you could download the jars from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/com/google/gwt/ and just replace the ones you need