# GWT-Polymer very first time

Tags: gwt, polymer-1.0

I'm studying about GWT and Polymer by JsInterop, it looks cool so I start with some base example. I generate a brand new gwt project using the `webAppCreator` command and not much more that copy down [this](http://vaadin.github.io/gwt-polymer-elements/demo/#iron/IronListSample) Vaadin example. After a successful compile I run `gwt:run` and an alert prompt on browser, here it is:

[image]

What's wrong? I'm using GWT 2.8, Polymer 1.0, Vaadin polymer libs 1.2.3.0 and Java 1.8.

Comment: My bad, I totally miss [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686918/trying-to-get-xjsinteropmode-js-working?rq=1) question. It solves this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I manage this one by myself. I got [this](https://github.com/fpezzati/gwtrepo) github project if anyone want to take a look at GWT 2.8 and Polymer 1.0 setup.